# GoogleApiClient can't connect on signed apk works on debug

Tags: android, google-play-services

I just finished my app and generated a signed apk and uploaded the apk to the play store as alpha to test.

Everything seems to be working as expected, except the Google games services. I see the green box with connecting to google play services and then a green spinner for a couple seconds but it then proceeds to fail with the following message in logcat

`ConnectionResult{statusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED, resolution=PendingIntent{3b445e29: android.os.BinderProxy@6050db6}, message=null}`

When i run my application from android studio it works fine any ideas?

Here is my code for connecting:

```
 mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(connectCallback)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(connectFailed)
            .addApi(Games.API, gamesOptions).addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
            .build();
 mGoogleApiClient.connect();
```

Comment: Sorry. I get the problem you are aiming to solve but the post itself is a bit vague. What have you done so far to solve the issue? Have you checked similar posts here in the community? Have you tested it on multiple devices? More info you can provide, more accurate answers you'll get from the community.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was on the testing was not activated as indicated here "https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/troubleshooting" Check that test accounts are enabled. After enabling beta testers it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This is because when you install the application for the first time, you are required to sign in Google Play services.You need to implement following callback method:

```
 @Override
        public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
          Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed() called, result: " + connectionResult);

          if (mResolvingConnectionFailure) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed() ignoring connection failure; already resolving.");
            return;
          }

          if (mSignInClicked || mAutoStartSignInFlow) {
            mAutoStartSignInFlow = false;
            mSignInClicked = false;
            mResolvingConnectionFailure = BaseGameUtils.resolveConnectionFailure(this, mGoogleApiClient,
                connectionResult, RC_SIGN_IN, getString(R.string.signin_other_error));
          }

          switchToScreen(R.id.screen_sign_in);
        }

@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode,
            Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, responseCode, intent);

        switch (requestCode) {
            case RC_SIGN_IN:
                Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult with requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN, responseCode="
                    + responseCode + ", intent=" + intent);
                mSignInClicked = false;
                mResolvingConnectionFailure = false;
                if (responseCode == RESULT_OK) {
                  mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                } else {
                  BaseGameUtils.showActivityResultError(this,requestCode,responseCode, R.string.signin_other_error);
                }
                break;
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, responseCode, intent);
    }
```

You can refer to the sample project as well, https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples

Comment: Sorry for my late reply but i allready have these callbacks in my code.

Comment: Do you have BaseGameUtils class in your project? It should invoke resolveConnectionFailure and ask for sign in to Google Play service.Could you add some log checking in onActivityResult. i pretty sure it does not invoke the case RC_SIGN_IN as well.